# Record not updating through AJAX request in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax

I am using jquery ajax in `laravel` for update data from database. I wrote this code and the $ajax() part not working. but everything before that working great. Please let me know where I am doing wrong?

1) AJAX function:

```
$(".Editform").click(function() {var id=$(this).attr("id");
 // alert(id);
$("#saveBtn").on ('click',function() {  var name = 
 // alert(name);
$("input[name=name]").val();
$.ajax({type:'POST',url:'edit-records',data:{id:id,name:name },success: 
  function(result){alert.show(); $('#MyModal').modal('hide');   
  console.log(result);}});});});
```

2) Controller:

```
public function updaterec(Request $request, $id)

{
    $name = $request->input('name');
    DB::update('update m_employee set employee_name = ? where employee_id = ?',[$name,$id]);
    echo "Record updated successfully";

}
```

3) web.php:

```
Route::post('edit-records','viewemployeeController@updaterec');
Route::get('view-records','viewemployeeController@index');
```

Comment: I am getting error :POST http://localhost/edit-records 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.js:8526
ajax @ jquery.js:7978
(anonymous) @ view-records:97
dispatch @ jquery.js:3074
elemData.handle @ jquery.js:2750

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you output the values inside `updaterec` to see if they're what you expect and if the function is even called?

Comment: Did you add csrf-token to your ajax setup ?

Comment: @AminKarimi.. I have not add csrf-token to the ajax setup

Comment: @EternalHour...could you please guide me on how to check if the function is getting called

Answer (score -1):

You should not use `$id` as parameter if it's not defined in the route.

Change your controller:

```
public function updaterec(Request $request)

{
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $id = $request->input('id');
    DB::update('update m_employee set employee_name = ? where employee_id = ?',[$name,$id]);
    echo "Record updated successfully";

}
```

---------OR---------

Change your Route and Ajax code:

```
Route::post('edit-records/{id}','viewemployeeController@updaterec');

 $.ajax({type:'POST',url:'edit-records/'+id,data:{id:id,name:name },success: function(result){alert.show(); $('#MyModal').modal('hide');   console.log(result);}});});
 });
```

Comment: error
send @ jquery.js:8526
ajax @ jquery.js:7978
(anonymous) @ view-records:97
dispatch @ jquery.js:3074
elemData.handle @ jquery.js:2750

Comment: Add this line before ajax call              $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
            });

Comment: @Sandeep..I tried ..but still same issue.  Is there any way to find out where it is getting stuck

Comment: Not sure why I am getting 500 internal server error for url:'edit-records'